# adding a web layer that supports Asynchronous reloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am at a loss. recently i have started learning Spring MVC by creating a web application that will post live updated sports scores. the business logic is basically done, but i have no idea how to create the web view. Specifically, Is there anything available that will allow the view to automatically refresh asynchronously from within Spring? If i want to do a refresh of the scores listing anytime new data gets added to the connected database, is that something that can be done with some sort of ajax dependency/ templating engine?

what about Angular.js or some variation of Meteor.js (atmosphere)? As you might tell, I'm pretty confused on how the web layer works..

any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Websockets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) to broadcast data to connected users as it gets added to the database.  With a PubSub pattern you can additionally limit the amount of messages to only the ones your client is interested in eg. filter out scores of non-visible games.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-msgsjs/